# Parse String between 2 text

Tags: javascript

I'd like to parse between a string

for example
str='uu2uuuu4uuu';

though when I use

alert(str.match(/(2\S+?4)+/ig));

I get '2uuuu4' with the outside when I only want 'uuuu'

Comment: what do you want to do? Do you want to remove the 2 and 4? If so, you could do a replace and just replace it with "uuuu" if that is the case. You are matching for 2uuuu4 right? the match function will return the parts that match up. If you were looking for uuuu that would a be different story

Comment: yea like the match gets it all though I'd like it to add the length from the start and subtract the length from the end so it just gives the middle and nothing else.

Comment: so you want the matched value and just remove the first element and the last element? Do a substring on the returned string value, removing the first element and keeping all the other elements. something along the lines of x.substring(1, x.length); where x is the matched value

Comment: I don't userstand? would you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the flag 'g' it will match the all string regardless to the '()' since it's grouping.
You need something like this

```
var str='uu2uuuu4uuu';
alert(str.match(/2([^24]+)+4/i));
```

Or to eliminate any numbers in the region

```
alert(str.match(/\d+([^\d]+)+\d+/i));
```

Comment: its not just number, could be anything str start end.

Comment: the first code, gives '2uuuu4,uuuuu' how would I get just 'uuuuu'?

Comment: str.match(/2([^24]+)+4/i)[1]
match always return an array that the first element is all the result

Answer (score 0):

What you want requires a lookbehind and lookahead. For example:

```
(?<=START)(.*?)(?=END)
```

Or just for non whitespace:

```
(?<=START)(\S*?)(?=END)
```

Or if you want only match if there is atleast one character:

```
(?<=START)(.+?)(?=END)
(?<=START)(\S+?)(?=END)
```

If you just rushed to add to your code, I'm sorry to tell you...

But **Javascript doesn't support regex lookbehind** (ie, `(?<=START)` is invalid in javascript). Ergo, you will have to drop the `g` flag and take the second result (index = 1) with a regex like this:

```
START(.*?)(?=END)
```

It would be like this:

```
var str = 'uu2uuuu4uuu';
var match = str.match(/2(.*?)(?=4)/i);
alert(match[1]);
```

Or this:

```
var str = 'uu2uuuu4uuu';
var match = str.match(/2(\S+?)(?=4)/i);
alert(match[1]);
```

You get the idea. I haven't found a better way to emulate a regex lookbehind in javascript.